# What is the path to signalr hubs when using ElmahR?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, elmahr

I am trying to add some custom functionality to ElmahR dashboard page and having some issues. I have started a new project, added ElmahR dashboard NuGet package. Configured all source applications and it is all working fine as expected.

Now I want to add some custom functionality to the dashboard page. As part of this I needed to add some UI to the dashboard page, a new Hub, JavaScript etc. The custom functionality is not related Error Logging. It is completely different. It is something we would like it to add to the dashboard page. I have added new Hub, JavaScript, HTML markups but it doesn't work as expected.

I ran into the following issues:

1. When i try to access /signalr/hubs, I get 404 Not found error. I searched online for this error and it usually happens if you haven't configured the Hub route. I tried to add RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs() in global.asax file. However it says that A route named 'signalr.hubs' is already in the route collection. Makes sense because I am using ElmahR and because it relies on SingalR, it would have already added it to the route collection. So what is the path to /singalr/hubs in ElmahR application? When using signalR in your standard asp.net application, the usual path to hubs is /signalr/hubs but what path is it when using ElmahR?
2. I am getting JavaScript error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined" at the line where I am trying to access hub.client. I guess it is failing because it is not able to find the new hub that i added.

Everything works fine if I copy the hub, associated JavaScript and HTML to a different ASP.NET MVC project. For some reasons it does not work with the Project that uses ElmahR. I know there is nothing wrong with the code in Hub and JavaScript as it works fine with a standard ASP.NET MVC project. Basically all I want to do is to add a singalR hub to a project that uses ElmahR. Also I can't seem to figure out the URL path to Hubs in an application that uses ElmahR. Usually the path is /signalr/hubs

UPDATE:

After further investigation, I figured the path to hubs in ElmahR dashboard application. It is /signalr101/hubs. However when requesting this, it errors: "Uncaught Error: SignalR: JavaScript Hub Proxy generation has been disabled". It appears that ElmahR would have disabled JavaScript proxies, probably by setting DisableJavaScriptProxies property of the application's IConfigurationManager to true (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/pull/1222). I think because of that I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined in my JavaScript at the line where it is trying to access hub.client. If the JavaScript proxy is disabled, then is there any extra work I have to do in my JavaScript and Hub so that I don't get this JavaScript error.

Comment: You are right, ElmahR uses proxies instead of explicit /signalr/hubs endpoint, that because of specific reasons related to implement (in future) dependencies with require.js. Are you trying to add a new Hub? If yes let me know, there are a few things I might expand to make it easier for you. Also, you figure it out right about /signalr101, the endpoint has a versioning number to avoid 500 errors in case old clients connect to newer ElmahR instances with a different SignalR version, this way the error is a "nicer" 404.

Comment: I just read better your answer and you do want to add a Hub, there is a 'built in' mechanism in ElmahR to do that which I could explain, I'm just not sure this is the right place. Please send me a message in Bitbucket and we'll discuss it there, sounds good?